# appending strings to NSMutableArray in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I need to append strings to an array kept inside of a dictionary each time a word matches a pattern of another word. The second line below (setObject) overwrites instead of appending.
The end result should be arrays in a dictionary where the the key(pattern) identifies many strings that fit that pattern.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *eqClasses = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [eqClasses setObject:tempWordStr forKey:wordPattern];
```

Is there an easy way to append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [eqClasses objectForKey:wordPattern];
if(!array) {
  // create new array and add to dictionary if wordPattern not found
  array = [NSMutableArray array];
  [eqClasses setObject:array forKey:wordPattern];
}
[array addObject:tempWordStr];
```

Comment: Very helpful -thank you.  And how will this array be iteratively added to the dictionary?  (My goal is to have a dictionary with thousands of arrays, each array using the wordpattern for key, new arrays added dynamically, new strings added dynamically)

Comment: the array is already in the dictionary, the code just adds the string object to it at the end

Comment: What I mean is, the loop needs to add arrays (based on wordpattern) and add strings to this arrays.  So the array may or may not be already added.  What would the code look like to 1.check if array exists (by wordpattern) 2. add the new array (or not), add the new string to the array.  (I am new to objective C )

Comment: That makes sense now - thank you. I would up vote you but I am still new here and my reputation is not up yet.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that the values in the dictionary should be arrays, but it looks to me like eqClasses contains NSStrings (tempWordStr). Don't you need to create an NSArray to hold the NSStrings associated with a keyword and then make the array the value in the dictionary that corresponds to the keyword? If the dictionary already contains the key, you need to retrieve the array associated with the key, add the new string to the array, and then call setObject using the array with the key.

Comment: Yes, I am struggling I guess.  I need to have a dictionary that dynamically adds thousands of arrays and the arrays dynamically add thousands of strings.  Each array is represented by a a wordpattern (the key in dictionary) and the value is the actual array.

Comment: Could you include a snippet to illustrate your suggestion?